# Django Football Simulation - Getting "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" browser message when looping through views

Tags: python, django, loops, redirect, django-views

I have a list of 16 games to simulate for Week 1 of this football simulation.

I have a VIEW called "simulate_game" that kicks off a simulation of the first game in the list using list index=0 (redirecting to some other views, HTML templates in the process), adds 1 to the index variable, and then redirects back to the "simulate_game" view in order to simulate game #2, and so on and so forth.

When testing, i keep getting "too many redirects" warnings. Is there a better way to loop through data than this? I've been searching the internet for a while now with no luck. I feel like there is some fundamental concept that I'm unaware of.

Here's a very basic version of what i'm doing:

**urls.py file:**

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('view1/', views.view1, name='view1'),
    path('view2/', views.view2, name='view2'),
    path('view3/', views.view3, name='view3'),
]
```

**views.py file:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import random

def view1(request):
    request.session['list'] = ['game{}'.format(n) for n in range(16)]
    request.session['index'] = 0
    request.session['score'] = {}
    return redirect('view2')

def view2(request):
    index = request.session['index']

    if index == 0:
        text = 'simulation has begun!'
        return render(request, 'template1.html', {'text':text})
    else:
        return redirect('view3')

def view3(request):
    lst = request.session['list']
    index = request.session['index']
    game_num = lst[index]

    r1 = random.randint(0,28)
    r2 = random.randint(0,28)

    request.session['score'][game_num] = [r1, r2]

    if index == len(lst) - 1:
        text = 'simulation complete'
        return render(request, 'template2.html', {'text':text})
    else:
        request.session['index'] = index + 1
        return redirect('view2')
```

**template1.html file:**

```
{{text}}
<form action="{% url 'view3' %}">
  <input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

**template2.html file:**

```
{{text}}
```

And here's the error I'm getting in the browser:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: With the current amount of information, we can not give a proper answer. Share a minimal working example: a view for example (where you can remove non-relevant details) that results in this error.

Comment: Ah sorry - i've added some example code above!

Comment: Thanks Aakash, tried changing the variable from "list" to "lst" but i'm still having the same issue. Also, i'm looping between view2 and view3 on purpose in order to incrementally simulate each game one at a time. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you redirecting between simulations rather than simulating all of the games at once?

Comment: This is a simplified version of what i'm actually doing. In reality, i'm utilizing different views and HTML depending on which teams are involved in each game. Accordingly, i can't use a regular "for" loop in the views.py file because the request needs to be passed on elsewhere so often.

Comment: Unless...is there a way to render the request to an HTML template midway through a for loop, and then have the request return to where you left off in said for loop thereafter?